# Gurobi: get LHS (left-hand side) of a constraint

Tags: python, constraints, linear-programming, gurobi

As written [HERE](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/attributes.html) (or [HERE](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/linear_constraint_attribut.html)), one can get the sense (<, =, >) and the RHS (right-hand side) of a constraint like this:

```
for cnstr in model.getConstrs():
    print(cnstr.sense, cnstr.rhs)
```

How can one get the coefficients in a constraint? I checked the attributes of variables and models, but found nothing of the sort.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to walk the object from the LHS. Assuming your model consists of only linear constraints, this looks like the following:

```
for cnstr in model.getConstrs():
  print("Constraint %s: sense %s, RHS=%f" % (cnstr.ConstrName, cnstr.Sense, cnstr.RHS))
  row = model.getRow(cnstr)
  for k in range(row.size()):
    print("Variable %s, coefficient %f" % (row.getVar(k).VarName, row.getCoeff(k))
```

You can also adapt this for quadratic constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems that one way is using the Model.getCoeff() function:

```
for cnstr in pre.getConstrs():
    for var in pre.getVars():
        print(pre.getCoeff(cnstr, var), end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching, i been looking for the example based in the table

[image]

```
    m = gp.Model(....)
    for c in m.getConstrs():
      lhs = c.rhs - c.slack
```